# Angular add Observable result inside Map

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, google-places-api

I currently have a method in my service that retrieves a collection from Firebase (Firestore) and returns it as an observable.

```
getInstallers(): Observable<any[]> {
    const installersCollection = this.afs.collection<Installer>('installers');
    return installersCollection.snapshotChanges().map(installers => {
      return installers.map(i => {
        const data = i.payload.doc.data() as Installer;
        const id = i.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      });
    });
  }
```

I have another method which utilizes google places api and returns an observable of a place when place_id is passed to it.  I'm not going to include all of it because it's kind of long just know that it returns an observable of a google place object.

```
getPlaceDetails(placeId): Observable<any>
```

What I'm trying to do is something like this...

```
getInstallers(): Observable<any[]> {
    const installersCollection = this.afs.collection<Installer>('installers');
    return installersCollection.snapshotChanges().map(installers => {
      return installers.map(i => {
        const data = i.payload.doc.data() as Installer;
        const id = i.payload.doc.id;
        this.getPlaceDetails(data.placeId).subscribe(place => {
          return { id, ...data, ...place }
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

However this causes the method to return void.  I'm trying to figure out a way to add the data I receive from my getPlaceDetails observable to the data that is mapped coming from my firebase collection.  Thanks!

Comment: Try a switchMap as shown here: https://netbasal.com/understanding-mergemap-and-switchmap-in-rxjs-13cf9c57c885

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use swtchMap

```
getInstallers() : Observable<any[]> {
     const installersCollection = this.afs.collection<Installer>  ('installers');
     return installersCollection.snapshotChanges().switchMap(installers => {
        let arrayOfObservables = installers.map(i => {
         const data = i.payload.doc.data() as Installer;
         const id = i.payload.doc.id;
         return this.getPlaceDetails(data.placeId).map(place => {
            return { id, ...data, ...place }
         });
        });
        return Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfObservables);
     });
   }
```

And in some oyher place call it:

```
 this.getInstallers().subscribe(data => {
   // here we have resukt
 })
```

Comment: My intellisense says that Property 'switchMap' does not exist on type 'DocumentChangeAction[]'.  Not sure what that means or what it's referring to.

Comment: In my console it's giving me an error saying installers.switchMap is not a function

Comment: I've edited my answer. So now switchMap will return array of this.getPlaceDetails values for each installer.

Comment: More about higher-order observables in my video course https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/hands-rxjs-web-development-video